# Instamojo Android SDK Payment callback not received

Tags: android, payment-gateway, instamojo

Im using instamojo SDK "com.instamojo:android-sdk:3.0.0".
Currently using TEST environment for payment.
Only Netbanking is working for TEST. But the problem here is, as soon as the payment via Netbanking is completed, the SDK redirects to the redirect URL but not closing the transaction window, thus the "onInstamojoPaymentComplete()" function is not called.

[image]

Here the above screen is displayed as soon as the payment is done via netbanking(TEST). But the Payment Activity is not closed even after the payment is completed. When I click on the back button, there a dialog pops up showing do you want to cancel the transaction? . If i press Yes then, the "onPaymentCancelled()" is triggered. 
What might be wrong Here ?

Comment: did you find any solution for production?

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem and fixed it by configuring

**redirect_url** value to 'https://test.instamojo.com/integrations/android/redirect/'

Because the sdk will initiate the callback() once it reaches it's redirect url.

Comment: Iam getting ANR screen on " onInstamojoPaymentComplete ", while perform anything on that method, do you have any solutions for that?

Answer (score 3):

need to add **redirect_url** as  'https://test.instamojo.com/integrations/android/redirect/'

in the request payment api where we are sending name, amount, currency, etc

Comment: I am also facing same issue but i am using Production Environment . So please give me any solution.

Comment: @SoniKumar, have you found any solution for production environment ?